# Show random questions and answers from XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, random

I'm trying to build a single page HTML app to show questions and answers in randomized order.

Here's the desired functionality:

1. A random question from a XML file is shown.
2. User clicks a button on the page and the question is replaced with the related answer in the XML file.
3. User clicks (preferably the same) button and steps 1-2 are repeated. However, I would like the new questions to be only pseudo random: user should not see the same questions again during one session before all other questions in the XML file are already shown.

Because I'm trying to achieve mobile app like user experience, I wouldn't like any page reloading to happen after the initial page load, but the Q&As should be shown immediately when user taps the button.

Am I correct that this could be done with using JavaScript/jQuery only? I can also use PHP if needed, but pure JS implementation would be more interesting.

I would be very grateful if somebody could give me some quidance how to solve this problem.

Comment: Well you need to have a specific question, if you provide zero code we can do nothing for you. Start building your app, discover by yourself and if you face problems ask for help here

Answer (score 0):

given that your button has the class "button", you show the question on a div with class "question" and you have your xml saved on a variable, let's say questions, the following jQuery code should do the trick

```
var q;
$( '.button' ).click( function(){
    if( q == false ){
        q = $( questions ).sort( function(){
            return Math.random() > 0.5
        } ).first();
        $( '.question' ).text( q.children( 'question' ).text() );
    }
    else{
        $( '.question' ).text( q.children( 'answer' ).text() );
        $( questions ).first().remove();
        q = false;
    }
} );
```

I assume your xml looks like this:

```
<entry>
    <question>Here lies a question.</question>
    <answer>And here is the answer!</answer>
</entry>
<entry>
    <question>Here lies another question.</question>
    <answer>And here is the answer!</answer>
</entry>
```